# Windows Server Requirements to install SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server

Our organisation is planning to create a database for the existing spreadsheets. I have a seen a lot of articles on installation of SQL Server Express. But I couldn't find any information about the prerequisites for the installation (like installing the database engine on a windows server so that the database can be accessed from multiple computers etc).

I want to configure the database such that multiple users and can access it through SSMS.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Comment: Thanks for the reply tinka,But Its not clear in the link if i should install the database on a server or any computer to make it remotely accessible for multiple users

Comment: you can install any windows machine doesn't matter just make sure `32` and `64` bit system

Answer (score 0):

Please check following MSDN page for SQL Server 2014 hardware and software requirements
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Then you can switch to any SQL Server version on this page using Other Versions drop down
Search for Express for SQL Server Express Edition requirements on the page

Comment: Thanks guys,So I can install SQL Server Express Database engine on any laptop/PC and can connect from any other system through SSMS without using windows server?

Comment: @EshwarK The limitation is not going to be where you install the DB, but how many connections the OS can accept.  That will depend on the OS, but as an example Windows 7 will accept 20 simultaneous connections.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Peter

Answer (score 0):

For SQL 2016, [here is a list of all operating systems that support SQL Express](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#TOP_Breadth). More specifically, it does not require Windows Server, however, it does require Windows 8 or higher.  SQL 2014, [requires Windows 7 or higher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.120%29.aspx#TOP_Breadth).

Also be aware of some of [its limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc645993.aspx#CrossBoxScale) (though In your case, I don't believe this will be an issue).

Comment: Thank you @mateuscb..I've been told by my mentor that we would require a windows/unix server for the database so that it can accept remote connections from different users. Wasn't sure if it is true